# Library to allow use of Pi camera in projects?

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, pi-zero, cross-compilation, shared-libraries

I've been looking for a library so that I can take pictures on the pi using the pi  camera (not a usb webcam). I've tried [RaspiCam](http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40) but that is having issues compiling in visual studio 2015 (yes i'm not developing on the pi itself).

Is there another library that allows images to be taken from the pi camera?

Comment: What operating system are you running on the Pi? Windows IoT doesn't support the Pi camera in any way.

Comment: I'm developing on Windows 10 then running in on raspian

Comment: That's not going to work, visual studio can't do that.

Comment: Actually, [it might](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/crosscompiler/), but I don't fancy trying it. Looks complicated! It'll be slower, but you'll probably have better results shifting your source files over to the Pi and compiling it there.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? So far all the code that I've written has worked with it, this being a bit more fussy than the other stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to use the camera from C/C++ is to use libmmal (this is the library used by `raspistill` and `raspivid`). The source is part of the [userland repository](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland), specifically look under `interface/mmal` in there and you'll find all the headers.

For examples of MMAL use, have a look at the `raspistill` and `raspivid` source code, which you can find under `host_applications/linux/apps/raspicam` in the same repository. Whether this will compile under Visual Studio I don't know (from goobering's link it looks like it's using GCC, so there's a chance).

Comment: Cool, I'll look into this and see what happens and report back in a week or so :)

Comment: Ok, I tried to get this going but there were quite a lot of errors when i tried to make it work with Visual Studio. I ended up using the Python camera version and then just stated a python engine and called the python methods from that in C#. I might look back into this at some point just to see if it can be done...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use gstreamer with Raspicam. I only used gstreamer with Pi Zero streaming from cheap USB webcam to LCD [(see details)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=161551). It has a huge number of  plugins you can just use. And you can write your own plugins (I have not done that yet, GStreamer Plugin Writer's Guide, gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/pwg/html/).
[image: see details]

Hermann.